# I can only upload the same file one time

Tags: plupload

I successfully integrate plupload on my website. I can upload files without problems but I cannot upload the same file multiple times.

PS: the problem only occurs with Internet Explorer. I don't have any problems with Google Chrome.

For example:

1. I upload 'hello.jpg'
2. The upload starts immediately
3. When upload finished, I display an alert (no matter).
4. Then I try to upload the same file, and it does not work. Nothing happened. I set a breakpoint in the 'FilesAdded' event and it is never reached.

**BUT if I try to upload another file it is working well.**

**BUT if I press F5 (refresh) then i can upload the previous uploaded file.**

Any idea? I really would like to be able to upload the same file multiple times.

For example, if a user upload a file then realize something is wrong inside the file and modify something in this file and need to upload it again, then he cannot upload it again in my case...

Here is part of my code:

Html part:

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="pickfiles" href="#" class="btn ui-button-text-icon-secondary">Uploader</a>
</div>
```

Javascript part:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes: 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    unique_names: false,
    browse_button: 'pickfiles',
    container: 'container',
    max_file_size: '5mb',
    url: pFiles.addFileUrl,
    multi_selection: false,
    multipart: true,
    multipart_params: { "type": "undefined" },
    filters : [{title : "Adobe PDF files", extensions : "pdf"}], 
    flash_swf_url: pFiles.uploadFlashUrl,
    silverlight_xap_url: pFiles.uploadSilverlightUrl,
    resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 }
});

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
    uploader.state = 1;
    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
    uploader.settings.multipart_params["type"] = $('#type').val();
    uploader.start();
    up.refresh();
    $('#messages').show();
});

uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function (up, file) {
    $('#messages').html('Progression: ' + file.percent + "%");
});

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, response) {
    var msg = $.parseJSON(response.response).Message;
    alert(msg);
});
```

PS: my current version of plupload is 1.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I simply had to install the 2.0 version of plupload.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line:

```
unique_names: false
```

to

```
unique_names: true
```

From the documentation:

> unique_names
>
> Generate unique filenames when uploading. This will generate unqiue filenames for the files so that they don't for example collide with existing ones on the server.

Comment: I already tried changing `unique_names` but it does not work neighter. The problem is not located server side. As explained in my question, I set a breakpoint in the javascript file (in the `FilesAdded` event) and this breakpoint is never reached. I also noted that the dialog opened to choose files already contained the filename previously used and when the previous file is equal as the current one it seems plupload ignore it !! I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

you to call `destroy()` method after upload process is done. Then initiate it again